How to make nx vite react monorepo project's relative path work?
I am creating a monorepo project with nx using vite
steps:

pnpm create-nx-workspace
within the apps folder I created a catalog and checkout with Nx Consle generate application
in the catalog's vite.config.ts:

  server: {
    port: 4200,
    host: 'localhost',
    proxy: {
      '/checkout': {
        target: "http://localhost:4201/",
        changeOrigin: true,
      }
    }
  },


I have a header navigation which navigate to the checkout page, but the style-sheet and the script is currently using relative path
e.g.


\<link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/styles.css" />,
\<script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script> 

but they are linked from the catalog app instead of checkout
So I expect the relative path to work according to each app but currently it is not, but rather it is sourcing from the port I opened
Like described above, I'd expect it to use relative path according to each app, but currently it is not. So whenever I have to do something with the path, it does not work as expected.
